# After involuntarily messed up with Atom config I removed it and reinstalled but still the config is the old messed up one

Tags: atom

I have involuntarily changed the config.cson of Atom and my wish in order to get it back I tried to install and reinstall the software several times but always the old messed up config insisted to be there. It has caused failed to load config.cson. I did all possible combinations to remove and install, booting in between, etc but memory of the old messed up config has never changed. Someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and write `sudo rm ~/.atom/config.cson` (type your password if required) in order to remove the file.

Try to reinstall atom now. Does it work?